# List out emojis

Tags: emojis

I am looking for a way to list out a complete "dictionary" of all the Emojis and their codes as shown here

[image]

I want the text in the boxes to be searchable as they are in this overview

This for a reference model to lookup emoji icons quicks since our users do not have access to Emacs or need access to it.

But so far it is the only app i have found that can list the descriptions as well as the codes like this.

We sometimes get lists of users, and need to deduce the code to an emoji , and emacs show this nicely but i would like to dump ALL emojis in emacs to a file shown as above.

Can it be done or does it exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need any kind of application for this, because all applications use the same standard for all characters called [Unicode](https://unicode.org/). Unicode is a set of specifications and data files that you can download and use.

[Technical Report 51](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/) covers how Emoji work in every respect. You may need to read this in order to understand the [Emoji Sequence Data for UTS #51](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/15.1/emoji-sequences.txt), which actually defines the emoji characters.

See also [this visual list of emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

Comment: The list here is also great. ty

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Emacs for dumping emoji's to a file you could evaluate the following code to write the emojis to the file 'emojis.txt' in your `default-directory`:

```lisp
(let* (emojis
       (emoji-filter (lambda (k v)
                       (when (and (>= v (string-to-number "1f000" 16))
                                  (<= v (string-to-number "1faf8" 16)))
                         (push (cons (format "%-4s%-8x%s" (string v) v k) v) emojis))))
       (sort-function (lambda (a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b)))))

  (maphash emoji-filter (ucs-names))

  (with-temp-file "emojis.txt"
    (dolist (e  (seq-sort sort-function emojis))
      (insert (car e) "\n"))))
```

We take the extra step of sorting the emoji's as the emoji's don't come out sorted from the maphash.

Of course, you can adapt the range (here from "1f000"/126976 to "1faf8"/129178) to your preferred range of emojis.

A nice website to inspect the unicode encoding table you can find [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=127744&utf8=dec).

Comment: The website for unicode you linked to @dalanicolai seems to be good enough. Thnx.